# Command-line: Create new partition using the largest continuous free space

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I want a shell script to create a new partition on `/dev/sdb` using all the available partitioned space, without touching existing partitions. 
My aim would be to create a new encrypted luks partition, but using

```
cryptsetup luksFormat /dev/sdb
```

would format the whole disk. Using something like:

```
cryptsetup luksFormat /dev/sdb2
```

is no option since `/dev/sdb2` does not yet exists, since we have one partition and the rest is unpartitioned space. 
So my plan was to create an partition first and then pass that partition as option to `cryptsetup luksFormat /dev/sdb<number>`, but I cannot figure out a clean and easy way to create a new partition using all unused space on a device.

Programs I had a look at: `parted` and `fdisk`.

For example ubiquity installer allows the option

```
d-i partman-auto/init_automatically_partition select biggest_free
```

which would do what I need, when I pass a recipe after that.

Any ideas how to achieve that in a script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this easily on GPT disks using `sgdisk`:

```
sudo sgdisk -n 0:0:0 /dev/sdb
```

For an MBR disk, the best option I know of is to use `fdisk`. It's not really designed to be scripted, though, so you'd need to create a Bash [here document](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) to pass it commands.

In either case, you'd have to figure out the number of the partition you just created in order to further set it up with `cryptsetup` (or whatever).